# novel where someone tells a story about a troll that lives under the bathtub and eats soap

Tags: identification-request

All I remember from this book is that one of the characters makes up a story for a child about a troll who lives under the bathtub and eats soap. I *think* the person telling the story was a nursemaid-type figure, but might have been another child. The novel seemed old-fashioned to me, so I pictured a claw-foot tub with the troll hiding in the shadows underneath, not a built-in tub sealed against the wall. I think the troll in the story was about a foot tall, with no clothes on. The novel had no fantasy elements, and this was clearly a made-up story.

It might have been one of the Hugo and Josephine books, but I no longer have access to a copy and I can't find anything online. I read it probably in the 2000s, in English (but I can't rule out that it was a translation). I think it was pretty old by then, though, with yellowing pages.